# Remove special character from customerId column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I want remove special character from `CustomerId` column.

Currently `CustomerId` column contains `¬78254782` and I want to remove the `¬` character.

Could you please help me with that ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the REPLACE T-SQL function :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CustomerId, '¬', '') FROM Customers;
```

Comment: Note that this would remove the `¬` everywhere it appears.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, That's right

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not really have any regex support, which is what you would probably want to be using here.  That being said, you could try using the enhanced `LIKE` operator as follows:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET CustomerId = RIGHT(CustomerId, LEN(CustomerId) - 1)
WHERE CustomerId LIKE '[^A-Za-z0-9]%';
```

Here we are phrasing the condition of the first character being special using `[^A-Za-z0-9]`, followed by anything else.  In that case, we substring off the first character in the update.